# OS Development - system memory reservation on startup

Tags: c++, memory, operating-system, kernel, paging

I am currently developing my own operating system kernel.

At the moment I am about to implement paging, and my problem is that I dont really understand what memory is reserved when the system starts, like the console video memory at 0x000b8000.

Where can I get information about what memory is reserved for the system and what I can use for my operating system?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps...

http://wiki.osdev.org/Expanded_Main_Page

OTOH, how can you be so sure that the system has a graphic adapter. Those reserved memory regions should be reported/reserved/allocated by the device drivers (video, DMA, sata, usb).

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86) tells me everything I need :) Thanks my friend!

Comment: Do not forget that there are other platforms like ARM, MIPS, SPARC. They have totally different architectures...